# Writing lists using only CONS command in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme, nested

Using only the cons command in the Scheme Programming Language, how can one write nested lists such as

'(a b (x y (m)))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: the `car` of a cons cell can be a cons cell too.

More particularly, the list you have is written in long form as:

```
(a . (b . ((x . (y . ((m . ()) . ()))) . ())))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(define a "a")
(define b "b")
(define x "x")
(define y "y")
(define m "m")

(define example (cons a (cons b (cons (cons x (cons y (cons (cons m '()) '()))) '()))))
```

Resultaat:

```
   example
 '("a" "b" ("x" "y" ("m")))
```